# Why tangent to electric field lines gives direction of electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields

Why do we use rise over run (i.e. tangent) only to determine the direction? Why not anything else? Is it simply because of ease of calculation OR convention?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_curve

Comment: The concept of tangent can be defined as a purely geometric entity without the need to reference any algebraic formulae.

Answer (score 1):

By definition the direction of the tangent to a electric field line at a point (taking account of the direction of the arrowhead) is the direction of the electric field at that point.

Comment: Why has this definition be chosen?

Comment: Because it produces a very useful visual representation of the electric field.

Comment: The tangent to a curve (here the the field line) has *nothing* to do with "rise and run" and the associated trigonometric function.

Comment: @mikestone I only mentioned the tangent and made **no** reference to the **gradient** (rise and run) of the tangent.

Comment: @Farcher. Sorry! This comment was directed at the OP who does mention "rise and run" in the first line of his question, so I assume that he is  confused by the two distinct meanings of "tangent"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, electric field is a physical quantity whereas electric field lines are just a way of visualizing the field. So, for your first question, no we do not *only* use tangent of electric field lines to determine direction of electric field.

Even though it is implied by the definition of electric field lines that they indicate the direction of electric field by their tangents; they are used mostly for visualization as they give a good idea for the direction of electric field for multiple points in an electric field.